# How to render HTML content coming from Model

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I have a wordpress like website in ASP.Net MVC 5, where I can create website for my customers. Now one of the customer's website needed a text box to add a html content. So, I added `[AllowHTML]` for that text box, so I am able to successfully save textbox content to DB. Now my question is how to render in front end. I mean I have a model property as

`public string htmlcontent {get;set;}`

and the value I am getting from Database is

`<p>abc</p>`.

Now what is the best way to render it in my cshtml file. If I do something like

`@Model.htmlcontent`

My output is simply `<p>abc</p>` as **Plain TEXT** But I want the DOM to understand the html content and attributes and render it accordingly.

Comment: If you allow that everyone can enter not only HTML, but also javascipt, which is then executed on every user's machine. Please get familiar with XSS (cross site scripting): https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: Only I have access to settings page as an admin. So basically only I can log in to settings page and make changes as per clients demand.

Comment: but I will read the article. thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the razor engine not to escape your string using `Html.Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.htmlcontent)
```

Comment: Can you put one line of explanation why `Raw` works but normal rendering w/o `raw` does not work.

Comment: By default all strings output through razor are escaped/encoded, so for example `>` becomes `&gt;`. By using `Html.Raw` you're telling the razor engine not to escape any characters in the output, sending it "raw" to the browser.